# `self` can not use as arguments of a hy macro

Tags: hy

The following macro tries to assign a member variable from init argument.

But

`name 'self' is not defined`

```
(defmacro optional_assign [x &optional [base self]]
    `(lif ~x (setv (. ~base ~x) ~x) (setv (. ~base ~x ) None) ))

(defclass clsa []
    (defn __init__ [self &optional y]
      (optional_assign y) 
      ))

(setv insa1 (clsa 123))
(print insa1.y) ;;=>123  
(setv insa2 (clsa))
(print insa2.y) ;;=>None
```

Answer (score 1):

The default argument is evaluated like an ordinary expression, so you want `[base 'self]`, not `[base self]`.

Also, you're missing a `~` for the first mention of `x` in the body.